# React-navigation navigate 2 screen or more forward specifying the index

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation V2 as a navigation library in my react-native project. I have 3 screens on the same Stack:

```
const CardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: { screen: ScreenA },
    ScreenB: { screen: ScreenB },
    ScreenC: { screen: ScreenC }
  },
  navigatorConfig);
  });
```

how can I navigate from "Screen A" to "Screen C" and that "Screen B" be mounted, in case I do back from "Screen C" it is returned to "Screen B", I try this with a dispatch in the navigation:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenB' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenC' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

I don't want to do a `reset` as it does a strange effect on the animation, and besides I don't want to mount all the screens again, the idea is only a way to use the `navigate` function like this:

```
const navigateAction = StackActions.navigate({
  index: 1,
  routes: [
    ({ routeName: 'ScreenB' }),
    ({ routeName: 'ScreenC' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

But only the following actions are supported: Reset,Replace,Push,Pop, PopToTop.

Stack actions reference:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this type of navigation is possible?